# How to calculate the average number of rating star

Tags: sql

i has a query a table in db

```
SELECT book_id,rating_date
from review r
ORDER BY book_id, rating_start
```

and result like

```
id | book_id | rating_date
1  |    3    |     1
5  |    3    |     2
6  |    3    |     3
2  |    5    |     3
7  |    5    |     4
9  |    5    |     5
```

how i display average number of rating star of each book with formula like

```
AR = (1*a+2*b+3*c+4*d+5*e) / (a+b+c+d+e)
o Where AR is the average rating
o a is the number of 1 star ratings
o b is the number of 2 star ratings
o c is the number of 3 star ratings
o d is the number of 4 star ratings
o e is the number of 5 star ratings
```

Comment: What are a, b, c, d, and e values in your example? 
Do you have a rating number/star or just rating dates? Why dates are integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just normal AVG values based on book_id.

```
   SELECT AVG(rating_star) FROM review GROUP BY book_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by simply using the `AVG()` function as follows:

```
SELECT AVG(rating_star)
FROM review
```

Edit: I assumed `rating_start` was a typo

Comment: this calculates the overall average. for calculating the averages separately for each book, look at @Losbaltica 's answer